# What is the fastest way to Render to a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, rendering, game-engine

So I am making some kind of small 2D - Game-Engine.
So far it is working quite okay, however the Rendering is a bit jittery, and has a lag every 1-2 Seconds (frame freezes for half a second). Even though this is hardly a deal breaker, it is stil an annoyance that should be sorted out, and I am obviously kind of curious about why this is.

So my current Method to Render the frame is by manipulating the g2d Object of a certain JPanel:

(img is the Map that is drawn. This method is part of a Class that has all Information like width and height of the Screen and Position of the Camera. (so PosX,PosY,width,height are taken from the Instace of the Object this is called on)

```
public void DrawByManipulatedMapSubimage(BufferedImage img, Graphics2D g2d)
{
    if (isActive)
    {
        BufferedImage img2 = img.getSubimage(PosX, PosY, width, height); 
        g2d.drawImage(img2,0,0,null);
        List<MapObject> MapObjects = Map.getObjectInformation();
        List<UiComponent> UC = this.UI.getUiComponents();

        int l = this.Map.getObjectInformation().size();

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            MapObject MO = MapObjects.get(i);
            int MOX = MO.getPosX();
            int MOY = MO.getPosY();
            BufferedImage MOB = MO.getCurrentAnimation().getCurrentlyActiveFrameAsBufferedImage();

            g2d.drawImage(MOB, MOX - PosX, MOY - PosY, null);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < UC.size(); i++)
        {
            UiComponent CC = UC.get(i);
            if (CC.isVisible())
            {
                Point P = CC.getPosition();
                int x = P.x;
                int y = P.y;
                g2d.drawImage(CC.getImg(),x,y,null);
            } 
        }
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(0);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Viewport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What this Basically does is, that it

1. Paints a Subimage of the currently active Map, based on where the User is viewing from (the Camera-View in a Way)
2. Draws the BufferedImage of the Current Animation of all attached MabObjects (basically Everything that is due to change; like the Player, Npcs, moving trees, spaceships, whatever) on top of that.
3. Draws all attached UserInterface-Components on top of the last two things.
   (just things like character portraits for example; no buttons or anything interactable)

The thing that is making me curious is, that this can't be a case where a Program is using so much cpu that it just can't keep up with Rendering, as the Program has the same lags running with x attached extras as without any.
Also this program uses about 5% of my CPU (at 30fps)

So the Problem has to be somewhere else.
Do you maybe have an idea to optimize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The thing that is making me curious is, that this can't be a case
>   where a Program is using so much cpu that it just can't keep up with
>   Rendering, as the Program has the same lags running with x attached
>   extras as without any. Also this program uses about 5% of my CPU (at
>   30fps)

- caused by `Thread.sleep(int)`, you shouldn't to use Thread.sleep(int), only in the cases that you want to simulating some long and expensive sleep, otherwise to use Timer
- `Thread.sleep(0)` == `zero miliseconds` freeze current JVM instance untill loop ended, nothing happens untill this loop freezed by `Thread.sleep()` ended,
- latency in Native OS isn't under 16milisecond, 25 could be a limit, but to use Timer instead with this value

---

> g2d.drawImage

- for todays `Java6/7`

  1. should be invoked by override `paintComponent` in `JPanel`,
  2. 1st. code line inside `paintComponent` should be `super.paintComponent()` == reset all previous painting, otherwise painting cumulated
  3. delayed or repainted by [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) on reasonable frequency 33-50 milisecond
- it about good practicies in painting in Swing to store current snapshot in `BufferedImage`, and all volatile variables or Objects could be stored in `List<Whatever>`, inside paintComponent to g2d.drawImage and for rest of painting to loop inside prepared `array of Object`s (`List<Whatever>`)

---

for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Comment: you should add Swing Timer (50-125) with container.repaint() called after coordinates is changed in ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

You are probably suffering from Garbage Collection pauses, due to excessive allocation. Some methods look very suspicious regarding allocation (e.g. "getCurrentlyActiveFrameAsBufferedImage" ).
Use VisualGC to check allocation rate, then improve your program or try to get a big eden. Large binary objects such as bitmaps/byte[] are allocated directly on OldSpace, so if you create too much of them, you'll trigger a lot of oldGC pauses. If this is the case, tweaking Eden size will not help.

Edit: check wether the 'pauses' correlate with GC by running your program with the -verbose:GC option